# Iterate through domain names and delete domains using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have a list of unused/unassigned domains in table format. It's actually a table inside a GDB. I want to build a model that iterates through this table and deletes the domain.

Is this possible with ModelBuilder?

I tried to create a field value iterator, however, it won't let me link it up with the Delete Domain tool.

I know it's possible with python, but has anyone successfully attempted this with ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find the Model builder answer, but I managed to create a script in python that did the job.

Here it is:

```py
##domain clean up script
##Created by: Ruchira Welikala
##Date: Aug 27, 2015

import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#Workspace where domains will be deleted from
gdbConnName = "Database Connections\\ProductionDB.sde"

#Workspace/Table where list of unused domains are located
UnusedDmnListTable = "C:\Scratch Workspace\domain_List.gdb\A_UnusedDomains"

#Field name that you're running the cursor on
fieldName = "name"

#Cursor initialization. Set the cursor to the table
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(UnusedDmnListTable)
txtfile = open('DomainsNOTDeleted.txt','w')

#Loop through and delete domains from workspace
for row in cursor:
        try:
                print "Deleting domain: " + (row.getValue(fieldName))
                arcpy.DeleteDomain_management(gdbConnName, (row.getValue(fieldName)))
                print "Deleted:" + (row.getValue(fieldName))
        except Exception:
                print "Domain " + row.getValue(fieldName) + " was not deleted."
                txtfile.write(row.getValue(fieldName) + "\n")
                continue

txtfile.close()
```

Comment: You should delete your cursor  (`del row, cursor`) after you are done using it to ensure proper closure. Or better yet, since you are on 10.1+, use [`da.SearchCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) with a `with` statement, which automatically closes and is considerably more robust and efficient.